# Why does componentDidUpdate not see newly inserted dom nodes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this strage case, maybe I am missing something from how react `componentDidMount` works, or maybe it is a strange behaviour (right know I can't provide a real fiddle with the jQuery plug in, but I am pretty sure the problem is wider than the plug in itself).

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {content: '<div id="target">ciao!</div>'}
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    const target = $('#target').init();
    this.target = target;
  },

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (condition) {
        this.target.destroy(); // this remove even the DOM node
    }
  },

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const target = $('#target').init(); // HERE PROBLEM! can't find the #target element
    this.target = target;
  }

  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.state.content}</div>;
  }
});
```

I can't understand why after the ´condition´ is true and the dom node are destroyed by the plug in, the `componentDidUpdate` does not find the `#target` that in my mind should have been "re-rendered" in the first render after `componentWillReceiveProps`. I expect to be there because it reads it from the initial state that never change.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can't render raw HTML like that without using the aptly-named [`dangerouslySetInnerHtml`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

Comment: @JoeClay is not the case. Anyway I tried and does not change anything..

Answer (score 1):

Since you are manipulating the react element (this.state.content) using jQuery, which makes React not able to detect changes to the rendered content. So when you render it first time

1. `componentDidUpdate` has the initial state, and the fully rendered component, including `#target`
2. after `$('#target').init()` is called, the rendered component is changed externally, without informing React
3. after `$('#target').destroy()` is called, the `#target` node is removed from DOM without informing React
4. therefore when in `componentDidUpdate` you call `$('#target').init()`, you are not able to locate `#target` because React did not detect any change in `#target`, and due to the fact that React does selective re-rendering, the `#target` is not regenerated.

So the one thing you can do is to update the state in componentWillReceiveProps ([in condition check](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)), note the `data-updated` field, this will make sure that React detects a state change for the `this.state.content`, and hence will re-render the component, and you will find the `#target` again in `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (condition) {
    this.target.destroy(); // this remove even the DOM node
    this.state.content = `<div id="target" data-updated="${Date.now()}">ciao!</div>`;
  }
}
```

Given this, I suggest you to have a look at [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) in React.

Comment: your answer has a lot of sense! Later at work I 'll try and let you know. I know refs, but since I am already "bypassing" React with jQuery in this casa I did not see problem using $ selectors.. do you think is better use refs?

Comment: There is not much difference in usage, but one of the argument could be the $('#target') finds everything in DOM (could conflict if there are any other '#target', also is performance in-efficient). Instead $(this.refs.target) makes this jQuery selector very scoped.

Comment: Thanks... I tried your solution but did not worked... it does not make any sense... cant uderstand why is not re-rendered by react, even with attributes differents

Answer (score 0):

In React you should never do `this.setState()` inside the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method, as it causes layout thrashing. 
See more about layout thashing here: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/08/beware-javascript-layout-thrashing/

The reason is that `this.setState()` causes a re-render (calls `render()` twice). And that happens once in the `componentDidMount()` and once in the actual render method. You should find a way to remove the `setState()` from the `componentDidMount` and your problem may be resolved. As an initial try, I would move the `this.setState()` inside the `componentWillMount()` method

Comment: Yeah you right, in fact I am not using setState, but settig modal on the "this" object, I will rewrite the example! Anyway, is not that the problem

Comment: How about your `this.setState({target: target})` in your `componentDidMount()`? Try to move that inside `componentWillMount()`

Comment: mmmm I think you dont seethe problem clearly.. If I move it to WillMount the dom nodes are not there, so I cant bind any jquery plugin